# How to get the number of elements in a JSON array stored as CLOB with Oracle 12c?

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

I'm storing a java class A as A_DOC in a clob column in my database.

The structure of A is like:

```
{

id : 123

var1: abc

subvalues : [{

 id: 1 
 value : a

 },
{
id: 1

value :b
}

...

}
]}
```

I know I can do things like

```
select json_query(a.A_DOC, '$.subvalues.value') from table_name a;
```

and so on, but how I'm looking for a way to count the number of elements in the subvalues array through an sql query. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use JSON_TABLE:

```
SELECT
    id, var1, count(sub_id) subvalues
FROM
    JSON_TABLE (
        to_clob('{ id: 123, var1: "abc", subvalues : [{ id: 1, value: "a", }, { id: 2, value: "b" } ]}'),
        '$'
        COLUMNS (
            id NUMBER PATH '$.id',
            var1 VARCHAR PATH '$.var1',
            NESTED PATH '$.subvalues[*]'
            COLUMNS (
                sub_id NUMBER PATH '$.id'
            )
        )
    )
GROUP BY id, var1
```

Comment: is there some simple function like `json_count('[...]')` or something?

Answer (score 13):

the function exists in Oracle 18 only

```
SELECT json_query('[19, 15, [16,2,3]]','$[*].size()' WITH ARRAY WRAPPER)  FROM dual;

SELECT json_value('[19, 15, [16,2,3]]','$.size()')  FROM dual;
```

Comment: Nice example, is ot possible get column name or column index?

Comment: `json_query` returns to me an array of ones.

Comment: @MarcoSulla This is a very late reply, but if you want the size of the outer array, use `'$.size()'` or if you have a field in a column in your table, `select json_value(mycolumn, '$.myarrayfield.size()') from mytable;`

Answer (score 1):

For PL/SQL you can use:

```
DECLARE
    arrSize NUMBER;
BEGIN
    -- Retrieve the size of the JSON array
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(json_value, '$.subvalue.size()')
    INTO arrSize
    FROM dual;

    -- Use arrSize as needed
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Size of the JSON array: ' || arrSize);
END;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).