# How to find the number of rows present in a json array in oracle?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, count

I want to find the number of rows in each json object. For example,

```
SELECT  A.firstName
FROM ABC c,
JSON_TABLE (c.abc_data, '$'
COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$.names[*]' COLUMNS (firstName PATH '$.value'))) AS A;
```

In the above code there are multiple objects like `$.names[*]` and each of these object has multiple sub elements like `firstName PATH '$.value'`. I want to find out the count of rows that is present in each object like `$.names[*]`.

Comment: Could you provide minimal reproducible test data ? That would make it a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the table and data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE abc ( abc_data CLOB CHECK ( abc_data IS JSON ) );

INSERT INTO abc (
  abc_data
) VALUES (
  '{"names": [
     {"value":1},
     {"value":2},
     {"value":3},
     {"value":4}
  ]
}'
);
```

Then, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67632460/67672962#67672962), you can use:

```sql
SELECT  a.firstname,
        JSON_VALUE(a.sz, '$[0]') AS sz
FROM    ABC c
        CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
          c.abc_data,
          '$'
          COLUMNS (
            NESTED PATH '$.names[*]' COLUMNS (
              firstName PATH '$.value'
            ),
            sz VARCHAR2(10) FORMAT JSON WITH WRAPPER PATH '$.names.size()'
          )
        ) AS A;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT  a.firstname,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.ROWID) AS sz
FROM    ABC c
        CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
          c.abc_data,
          '$'
          COLUMNS (
            NESTED PATH '$.names[*]' COLUMNS (
              firstName PATH '$.value'
            )
          )
        ) AS A;
```

Which both output:

> | FIRSTNAME | SZ |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 4 |
> | 2 | 4 |
> | 3 | 4 |
> | 4 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=89ac2ad9679b8a660ffaa7f6c6f52890)*